# Is there an assemblyof(), similar to typeof()

Tags: c#

If I need to get an assembly, I can do `typeof(LouisHowe.web.Program).Assembly`.

However, it would be a bit cleaner if there was a way to do `assemblyof(LouisHowe.web)` where I am using the assembly name.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, what would the identifier `LouisHowe.web` be here? Cannot be a namespace as multiple assemblies can contain the same namespace. The "Name" part of an `AssemblyName`?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, you're right. I asked thinking there might be some unambiguous way to get it. But you may be right, the only clean way is via a type.

Comment: Out of the box this is not possibe in c#, although the runtime would support it. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/ericlippert/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.

Comment: @thehennyy I don't think it does. `ldtoken` instruction only supports a method, type of field token, not an assembly.

Comment: @Charlieface You are right, i had that wrong in my mind, the instruction is not as flexible as i have thought. I think the linked article is relevant in that context non the less.